# How can I use my own HTML/FLUID Template for TYPO3 Extensions (from Repsository)

Tags: templates, plugins, typo3, fluid, extbase

At my old TYPO3-Extension "dmmjobcontrol", I'm using my own HTML-Template via TypoScript

```
plugin.tx_dmmjobcontrol_pi1.template.search = fileadmin/search.tmpl
```

Now, the new Extbase-Extension "Jobfair" (http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/jobfair/Index.html) uses FLUID Templates with ViewHelpers, Partials etc.

How can I use my own HTML-Snippets for the Frontend? I can read FLUID-Templates and I can write my HTML at /jobfair/Resources/Templates/Job/**List.html** into it. But after an Extension.Update my data will be lost. How can I solve this? I can't style my Frontend with CSS only, it's impossible. I need several HTML-Tags at my template.

How can I use my own Template at Extbase-Extensions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

In TypoScript Setup:

```
plugin.tx_jobfair {

  view {
     templateRootPaths {
       100 = fileadmin/templates/static/jobfair/Resources/Private/Templates/
       #100 = EXT:jobfair/Resources/Private/Templates/
     }

     partialRootPaths { 
       100 = fileadmin/templates/static/jobfair/Resources/Private/Partials/
       #100 = EXT:jobfair/Resources/Private/Partials/
     }

     layoutRootPaths {
       100 = fileadmin/templates/static/jobfair/Resources/Private/Layouts/
       #100 = EXT:jobfair/Resources/Private/Layouts/
     }
  }

}
```

Before, copy the Resources-Folder from the Extenstion into your /fileadmin-Folder and make your changes at the templates ..